# SQL date and time to secondate in hana

Tags: sql, datetime, hana

I am currently working in hana db I need to add a date column and a time column, so I can get a  timestamp format column currently I am trying this query

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP (T, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(concat(CONCAT(DATE,' '), ENDTIME) AS VARCHAR) AS T
    FROM "SCHEMA"."TBLTRACK"
);
```

Which throws me errors:

> Error executing Query:02[daydate],ENDTIME=[secondtime])

Here `DATE` is `DATE` type column and `ENDTIME` is `TIME` type column.

I have tried `cast`, `convert`, `to_timestamp` but it is not working since `DATEADD` seems not to be present in hana I am stuck can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Please post the **complete and exact** error message!

Comment: Error executing Query:02[daydate],ENDTIME=[secondtime])

Comment: check the data in the tbltrack table, because your sintax is rigth

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've found solution to my problem in one of the records( it had 10000 rows)the time was was not properly defined which threw the error.thank you for taking time to look at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no built-in function to recombine date and time.

You can however do this manually:

```
select time'10:10:57' as my_time
     , date'31.10.2014' as my_date 

     , to_varchar(date'31.10.2014') || ' '|| to_varchar(time'10:10:57')

     , to_seconddate(to_varchar(date'31.10.2014') || ' '|| to_varchar(time'10:10:57')) as combined_date_time
from dummy;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

TBTCO.strtdate is a date

TBTCO.enddate is a date

TBTCO.strttime is a time

TBTCO.endtime is a time

```
(
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_NVARCHAR(TBTCO.strtdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || TO_TIME(TBTCO.strttime), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
,
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_NVARCHAR(TBTCO.enddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || TO_TIME(TBTCO.endtime), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
)
```